# Is Pentaho or Spark faster than Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, pentaho

Please help me here. I have been told by a technical guy at my place that Pentaho and Apache Spark are faster than Java. Is this the right statement even? Apache Spark and Pentaho are frameworks whereas Java is a language. To me it seems like comparing apples to oranges. Am I right in thinking that or what am I missing? Appreciate thoughts on this.

Much thanks!

Comment: Yes. Apples vs oranges vs bananas

Comment: I think said person was trying to say "distributed processing frameworks like Spark are faster than a single computer running Java". Meanwhile Pentaho is a tool, not a framework, AFAIK

Comment: The speed of any racing car is limited by the road, except on the race track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both run in the JVM, so they cannot be "faster than Java"

They might be able to get work done faster than writing the best possible multi-threaded code yourself, or other slice & dice BI workload (at least, in the Pentaho case) but that of course depends on the hardware resources available. E.g Java on my gaming desktop would run faster than a Spark cluster on a few Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 0):

sql developer and pentaho : in one task i, think sqldeveloper is better 
but when use java connection pentaho is better than java connection JDBC